# How to Include empty values to list, that can be used (not losing its length) for a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm scraping a website. I want all the data I've collected to be used to create a dataframe `df`. Not knowing the best method to do so, I've used `.append` to fill in the values to an empty list. Then I use the same list to create a dataframe.

**The Problem** Some values I scrape are empty, but `.append` doesn't take them into the list. Thus lists are not equal in length to create a df from. I need to know which parts are empty because everything goes straight to the g sheets.

In the past, I've used `pd.series(python_list)`, but that just puts non-empty values first and fills up empty spots with Nan values. But that doesn't solve the problem, because it messes up the data table.

Here's the code:

```
job_title = []
job_link = []
job_employer = []
job_salary = []
job_posted = []
job_deadline = []

i = 0
while i >= 0:
    url = 'https://www.website.com/page=' + \
        str(i)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    if page.status_code == 200:
        job_elems = soup.find_all(
            'div', class_='cvo_module_offer_box offer_content')

        for job_elem in job_elems:
            try:
                title = job_elem.h2.text
                job_title.append(title)

                link = job_elem.h2.find('a')['href']
                link = link[2:]
                job_link.append(link)

                employer = job_elem.find(
                    'ul', class_='cvo_module_offer_meta').findChild().text
                job_employer.append(employer)

                salary = job_elem.find('span', class_='salary-blue').text
                job_salary.append(salary)

                posted = job_elem.find(
                    'ul', class_='cvo_module_offer_meta offer_dates').findChild().text
                job_posted.append(posted)

                deadline = job_elem.find(
                    'ul', class_='cvo_module_offer_meta offer_dates').contents[3].text
                job_deadline.append(deadline)
            except Exception as e:
                salary = None
                posted = None
                deadline = None
            # print(title)
            # print(link)
            # print(employer)
            # print(salary)
            # print(posted)
            # print(deadline)
            # print()
        i += 1
    else:
        break

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'Job Title': pandas.Series(job_title),
        'Link': pandas.Series(job_link),
        'Employer': pandas.Series(job_employer),
        'Salary': pandas.Series(job_salary),
        'When Posted': pandas.Series(job_posted),
        'Deadline': pandas.Series(job_deadline)
    })
```

Comment: you'll have to add a `try` & `except` block to every list, better to use a dictionary for this imo then just pass `np.nan` to blank values

Comment: Let's say an exception gets raised. You set `salary` et al. to `None`, but depending on when the exception occurs, you never actually call `job_salary.append`, etc.

Comment: `except Exception as e:` is bad practice. Why are you doing `while i >= 0:` when you only ever increment `i` by 1?

Comment: @AMC I've recently started learning to program. Since I'm new in this area, I learn via project-based learning. I might not do things most efficiently now, the goal is to get started and move forward.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the help! It works nicely! Such a silly mistake... it never occurred to me to call .append after an exception is triggered... lol

Comment: @Datanovice thanks for the tip! I'll need to take a look into it, when I'll start other mini-projects!

Comment: I believe converting the lists to Series when creating the DataFrame is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
i = 0
while i >= 0:
    url = 'https://www.website.com/page=' + \
        str(i)
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    if page.status_code == 200:
        job_elems = soup.find_all(
            'div', class_='cvo_module_offer_box offer_content')

        for job_elem in job_elems:
            try:
                title = job_elem.h2.text
                job_title.append(title)

                link = job_elem.h2.find('a')['href']
                link = link[2:]
                job_link.append(link)

                employer = job_elem.find(
                    'ul', class_='cvo_module_offer_meta').findChild().text
                job_employer.append(employer)

                salary = job_elem.find('span', class_='salary-blue').text
                job_salary.append(salary)

                posted = job_elem.find(
                    'ul', class_='cvo_module_offer_meta offer_dates').findChild().text
                job_posted.append(posted)

                deadline = job_elem.find(
                    'ul', class_='cvo_module_offer_meta offer_dates').contents[3].text
                job_deadline.append(deadline)
            except Exception as e:
                salary = None
                job_salary.append(salary)
                posted = None
                job_posted.append(posted)
                deadline = None
                job_deadline.append(deadline)
            # print(title)
            # print(link)
            # print(employer)
            # print(salary)
            # print(posted)
            # print(deadline)
            # print()
        i += 1
    else:
        break

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'Job Title': pandas.Series(job_title),
        'Link': pandas.Series(job_link),
        'Employer': pandas.Series(job_employer),
        'Salary': pandas.Series(job_salary),
        'When Posted': pandas.Series(job_posted),
        'Deadline': pandas.Series(job_deadline)
    })
```

Thanks to @chepner

Comment: If the div element doesn't contain one of the elements you're looking for, then it's guaranteed not to have any of the other ones? Or you simply wish to ignore it in that case?